# How to display a field in a content type template?

Tags: theming, entities

I edit my template field--field-email--customer.tpl.php and it works but I would like to display a field twice. I tried with this but it doesn't work :
    print render($content['field_nom']);

Comment: You need to correct the question. Your question title is a about content type template and description is about field template. You wants to display field in content type template or  field template ( field--field-email--customer.tpl.php).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can not use `$content` array in `field.tpl.php`.
You need to use `$items`.

> Available variables:
>
> ```
> $items: An array of field values. Use render() to output them.
> $label: The item label.
> $label_hidden: Whether the label display is set to 'hidden'.
> $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through CSS.
> ```
>
> from preprocess functions. The default values can be one or more of
>   the following:
>
> ```
> field: The current template type, i.e., "theming hook".
> field-name-[field_name]: The current field name.
> field-type-[field_type]: The current field type. 
> field-label-[label_display]: The current label position. 
> $element['#object']: The entity to which the field is attached.
> $element['#view_mode']: View mode, e.g. 'full', 'teaser'...
> $element['#field_name']: The field name.
> $element['#field_type']: The field type.
> $element['#field_language']: The field language.
> $element['#field_translatable']: Whether the field is translatable or not.
> $element['#label_display']: Position of label display, inline, above, or hidden.
> $field_name_css: The css-compatible field name.
> $field_type_css: The css-compatible field type.
> $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values
> ```